# Apache Cordova - uninstall globally

Tags: node.js, cordova, uninstallation

I've installed cordova via npm and i did it globally, now i would like to remove it to reinstall it on single app folder

Any clue on how to do it safely?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try `sudo npm uninstall cordova -g` to uninstall it globally and then just `npm install cordova` without the -g flag after `cd`ing to the local app directory

Comment: @enducat: how to uninstall for a specific project not globally?

Answer (score 28):

Try this for Windows:

```
    npm uninstall -g cordova
```

Try this for MAC:

```
    sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
```

**You can also add Cordova like this:**

1. If You Want To install the previous version of Cordova through the Node Package Manager (npm):

   ```
   npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13
   ```
2. If You Want To install the latest version of Cordova:

   ```
   npm install -g cordova
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 19):

Super late here and I still couldn't uninstall using `sudo` as the other answers suggest. What did it for me was checking where `cordova` was installed by running

```
which cordova
```

it will output something like this

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

then removing by

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/cordova
```

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when the cordova was installed globally on a different version of the node.

Being necessary to manually delete yourself as suggested in the previous comment:

which cordova

it will output something like this

/usr/local/bin/

then removing by

rm -rf /usr/local/bin/cordova

Answer (score 0):

worked for me:

```
which cordova
```

/opt/homebrew/bin/cordova

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using multiple node versions (say via nvm), you wont be able to uninstall if Cordova is installed against some other node version than the currently checked out version so switch to all other node versions respectively and run the command to get the job done

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
```