# How do you completely remove Ionic and Cordova installation from Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

How do I remove Cordova and ionic 1 and its dependency from my Ubuntu completely?. How to reinstall all again?

To install my ionic and its dependency i use this blog https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

I tried `npm uninstall -g cordova ionic` but it is not working

I am getting this two error

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/gopi/node_modules: "cordova"
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/gopi/node_modules: "ionic"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error actually says that your syntax is wrong for the command. Better try the commands individually:

For ionic:

```
$ npm cache clear
$ npm uninstall ionic
```

it should work as in:https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/install-ionic-on-mac/1854/6

If the above command does not uninstall ionic try the one below.

```
$ sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

For Cordova, the command :

```
sudo npm uninstall cordova -g
```

**Please note :** The -g is after.

**Refer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/19523868/1904479

Comment: i tried the both anwer but i am not able to do it.I have tried those you reffered in my case

Comment: It may means it's already uninstalled then, just try cordova --version and ionic --version?

Comment: just try whereis cordova to get the installation path and try cd to the installation directory an try uninstalling it from there

Comment: /opt/node/bin/cordova this is my cordova path i use cd /opt/node/bin and then used the command sudo npm uninstall cordova -g but i am getting the same error

Comment: i referred this blog form my ionic installation https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Comment: if your still seeing the version after removal (ionic -v) then you also need to delete it manually rm /usr/local/bin/ionic or wherever it resides.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was to run with the -g before

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Comment: What difference is your answer when compared to kailas answer. please answer something diffrent then others

Comment: The command just worked for me with the -g before the name "cordova", and kailas said the opposite.

Comment: This worked for me. I had ionic2 beta installed and executing these commands helped me uninstalled them in Mac.